# how to solve SDE

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

How to solve this SDE:
$dX(t)=X^\alpha(t)dt+\sigma X(t)dW(t), for X(0)=x_0$
$dW(t)$ is Wiener process. 
Also I have to use $f(t)=X(t)exp(-\alpha W(t)+1/2\alpha^2t)$ as integration factor. 
I tried to solve it looking at solutions of other SDE, but can't find the way for solving non-linear one as I started studying SDE just recently.

The only idea I have is to multiply both sides by integration factor. But what I can do with non-linear part?

Comment: What is $X^α(t)$? Is it $X(t)^α$ or some input function with parameter $α$ or some other $α$ modification of $X$ (stopped process?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A la Bernoulli you get for $Y=X^{1-α}$
$$
dY_t=(1-α)X_t^{-α}dX_t+\tfrac12(1-α)(-α)X_t^{-α-1}d\langle X\rangle_t
\\
=(1-α)(dt+σY_tdW_t)-\tfrac12α(1-α)σ^2Y_tdt
\\
=(1-α)\Big(1-\tfrac12ασ^2Y_t\Big)dt+(1-α)σY_tdW_t
$$
which is now linear in $Y$.